# Not able to execute jmeter script for 8 hours on azure cloud platform, as test getting completed automatically in 3 hours only

Tags: performance, jmeter, azure-cloud-services

I am running jmeter script on azure cloud platform and executing soak test. Mentioned total duration of 28 800 sec (8 hours) in jmeter script. But, execution getting completed automatically after 3 hours, (test not able to last long for 8 hours). I re run the test 2nd time also it gets finished in 3 hours only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the problem is with JMeter? I'm mainly asking because when I look at [Azure Load Testing Service limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/resource-limits-quotas-capacity#test-runs) I can see the default limit of the test duration set to 3 hours:

[image]

If you already contacted Azure Support to increase the test duration and test still ends prematurely - take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it normally contains the reason for the thread/test shutdown (you might want to [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) as well)